# Set mysql parameters with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

This is my code:

```
public function SelectSingleAccount($Id)
    {
        $Config = new Config();
        $mysqli = $Config->OpenConnection();
        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "CALL SelectSingleAccount", $accountId) or die("Query fail:     ". mysqli_error());

        $BusinessObject = new DL_Account();
        $ArrayResult = $BusinessObject->CreateObjectArray($result);
        return $ArrayResult;
    }
```

In phpmyadmin i have a parameter called id. How can i set this parameter in my code with the $Id value?

Comment: You're not passing $accountID to your sproc call. You're passing it as an argument to mysqli, and mysqli has NO idea what this extra parameter is all about.

Answer (score 0):

the stored procedure parameter goes inside the query string:

```
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "CALL SelectSingleAccount($Id)");
```

make sure that `$Id` is properly sanitized though